"JavaScript Heap Out of Memory Error in NestJS Application on Render"
I'm deploying a NestJS application on Render, and I'm encountering a "JavaScript heap out of memory" error during runtime. Here are the details and the steps I've taken so far:
Error Message:
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
Environment:

Node.js Version: 20.15.1
NestJS Version: 9.x
Render Configuration: Using default Render instance

Steps Taken:

Increased Memory Allocation:
I added --max-old-space-size=2048 to the start script in package.json to increase the Node.js memory limit. Here is the modified package.json script:

   "scripts": {
     "start": "node --max-old-space-size=2048 node_modules/.bin/nest start"
   }
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"]
  }
}

Additional Information:
The application processes large datasets from a MongoDB database.
I'm using Mongoose for database operations.
Questions:
Are there any additional configurations or optimizations I can apply to further increase memory efficiency?
Is there a better way to handle large datasets in NestJS applications to prevent memory leaks?
Could there be specific areas in my application code that I should investigate for potential memory issues?

Why not simply increase to 4048 then? I used to hit this error on build process, so this line just works.
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 npm run build


I've had this same problem and it's solved by adding filters to make it possible to select only the backend project folder. Read this article.
